# Exclude specific product from a function

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using a php function to add a small text after the ADD TO CART button in woocommerce for all the products. Works fine, but I need to exclude certain products from this.

Right now i'm using:

```
function woo_show_some_text_2() {
    echo '<p>customtext</p>';}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woo_show_some_text_2', 20 );
```

How could I add a part in order to exclude specific products by ID for example?

Thank you in advance.

Can't find a solution for this specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude specific product IDs from your function, you can use the following:

```php
function woo_show_some_text_2() {
    global $product;

    // HERE define the product IDs to be excluded
    $excluded_product_ids = array( 16, 18, 25 );

    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $excluded_product_ids ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<p>customtext</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woo_show_some_text_2', 20 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.